# Passing params NativeScript-Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to pass `params` to another route on `Nativescript`, but it always returns me `undefined`. I'm using the [nativescript-vue-navigator](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue-navigator).

currently on a screen I'm calling the following function

```
this.$navigator.navigate('/map', { props: { name: 'Rafael Augusto'} } )
```

and on my map screen, I'm trying to get it like this

```
export default {
  props: ['name'],
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score 1):

really late but might help others if the other two answers wouldn't work:

```
export default {
  props: ['name'],
  data() {
    name: this.name
  }
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try like this

```
export default {
  props: ['name'],
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.props.name)
  }
}
```

if this not work, then please share a playground sample, where I can check the issue

Answer (score 0):

On your destination page try defining the props like this:

```
props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    }
```

Works for me.